# Create a new file each time through a bash for loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, redirect, for-loop

I'm trying to create multiple shell scripts from a file with variable name. I have a bash for loop that creates the necessary lines but I want a new file each time through the loop. The script I currently have puts everything into one file. The input file (`test.txt`) has each variable on a separate line:

```
a
b
c
```

Here is the code I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash
num=0
echo $num
for x in $(<test.txt)
do
    echo \#\!/bin/bash
    echo \#SBATCH -N 1
    echo \#SBATCH -t 6:00:00
    echo \#SBATCH --job-name=${x}
    echo \. \~/\.profile
    echo time java -jar trimmomatic.jar PE -threads 20 ${x}_R1.fastq ${x}_R2.fastq
    num=$((num+1))

done  > trim_${num}.sh
echo $num
exit
```

This would write three loops with `a,b,c` variables to `trim_0.sh`. I want the `a` loop to be in `trim_0.sh`, the `b` loop to be in `trim_1.sh`, and the `c` loop to be in `trim_2.sh`.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for the correct way to read a file line by line. (Hint: it's not using a `for` loop.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the body of your loop in a block, like this:

```
while read -r x
do
    {
        echo '#!/bin/bash'
        echo '#SBATCH -N 1'
        echo '#SBATCH -t 6:00:00'
        echo "#SBATCH --job-name=$x"

        echo '. ~/.profile'
        echo "time java -jar /lustre/software/bioinfo/trimmomatic/0.32/trimmomatic.jar PE -threads 20 ${x}_R1.fastq ${x}_R2.fastq"
    } > "trim_$((num++)).sh"
done < test.txt
```

I've used quotes around each `echo` (single quotes where there aren't any shell variables involved, double quotes where there are) and removed your backslash escapes, which I don't think were necessary.

I've also used a `while read` loop, rather than a `for` loop to read the file. This makes no difference in your simple case but as pointed out in the comments, is the correct approach.

Alternatively, this may also be a good opportunity to use a heredoc:

```
while read -r x
do
    cat <<EOF >"trim_$((num++)).sh"
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -t 6:00:00
#SBATCH --job-name=${x}
. ~/.profile
time java -jar /lustre/software/bioinfo/trimmomatic/0.32/trimmomatic.jar PE -threads 20 ${x}_R1.fastq ${x}_R2.fastq
EOF
done < test.txt
```

Comment: This works great but if you use the quotes on lines where there are variables `${x}` then those don't get replaced but printed as is.

Comment: @ian_informatics note that I've used *double quotes* on those lines, so shell parameters are expanded.

Comment: @ian_informatics I've also updated my answer to show the use of a `while read` loop. The motivation for doing so is explained in [chepner's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627936/create-a-new-file-each-time-through-a-bash-for-loop/29628018#comment47401731_29627936) above.